# Glimpse: Unable to view anything in Execution or Timelines tab

Tags: glimpse

I am new in using Glimpse tool to diagnose the MVC application. I have installed Glimpse.Mvc4 and few other plug-ins. For example, Bundling & performance.
However, I am not able to view anything in "Execution", "Metadata", "Timelines" tab. Neither I am getting any use of "Bundling" plug-in visually.

Can anyone provide a better documentation place for these?

Comment: I found the cause of my issue. I have installed both Glimpse.Mvc3 & Glimpse.Mvc4 packages in my web application. Removing the latest one fix the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem.